# Bigquery Schema In AVRO Format

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

Is there any way to export only schema in AVRO format.I tried with BQ show command...but it doesnot support AVRO format.

PS: I need Only schema in avro format not with the data

Comment: Have you tried to export schema to `JSON` or `CSV` and then convert it to `AVRO` format?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an empty table from the table in question, followed by exporting it to avro, what you would get is an avro file with schema and no data.

```
CREATE TABLE mydataset.empty_table AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  
(partition_column) = 'xx'  AND 1 = 0
```

Then you can run the following golang snippet to extract AVRO schema

```
import (
    "os"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/linkedin/goavro"
)

func main() {

    avroLocation = "/tmp/myavro.avro"
    reader, err := os.Open("avroLocation")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    avroReader, err := goavro.NewOCFReader(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", avroReader.MetaData()["avro.schema"])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could download a very small amount of data then use `avro-tools` JAR to get the schema